# How can I replace a number of list elements between 2 boundary symbols in a python list

Tags: python

Given a list of zeros and boundary elements (ones) is there an efficient way to replace zeros, if less than N of them appear between ones?

```
For N=3:
[1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0] => [1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0]
```

Some more cases:

```
[1,0,0,1] => [1,1,1,1]

[0,0,1] => [0,0,1]

[1,0,0] => [1,0,0]
```

Comment: Only naive solution going in a loop for each element and counting zeros until the next '1' appears. Then going back and filling with ones. I was thinking there could be possibly a one-liner for doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your `list` to `str` and use `replace` method, then convert back to a `list`:

```
data = [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
n = 3

repl = (("1" + "0" * i + "1", "1" + "1" * i + "1") for i in range(1, n))
data_str = "".join(str(i) for i in data)
for r in repl:
while True:
    new_str = data_str.replace(r[0], r[1])
    if new_str == data_str:
        break
    else:
        data_str = new_str
new_data = list(int(s) for s in data_str)
print(new_data)
```

this will print

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

It looks a little convoluted but works fine if you have small lists not to cause any memory issues.

Comment: For [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1] this gives [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]. But I like the solution. Will try to fix this minor issue

Comment: Hm, so do you assume that the 1 in the middle is a boundary to both sides?

Comment: Yes, so the expected output for [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1] would be [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

Answer (score 2):

You could use the indexes if the `1`'s and check whether they are `n` elements apart. This should work:

```
l = [1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0]
n = 3

indexList = [i for i,j in enumerate(l) if j ==1]

for i in range(len(indexList)):
    try:
        if indexList[i+1] - indexList[i] < n+1:
            tmp = [1 for j in range(indexList[i+1] - indexList[i])]
            l[indexList[i]:indexList[i+1]] = tmp

    except IndexError:
        pass
```

Output:

```
>>> l
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the stack functionality of a `list`. Run through the list of numbers and add it to the stack, count the number of zeros added and compare it to `N` when a 1 follows, then pop `count` times when `count` < `N`:

```
data = [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
n = 3

new_data = []

zeros_found = 0
for number in data:
    if number == 0:
        zeros_found += 1
    elif 0 < zeros_found < n:
        for i in range(0, zeros_found):
            new_data.pop()
        zeros_found = 0

    new_data.append(number)

data = new_data
```

Appending is `O(1)` and poping from the stack is `O(1)`, so the complexity will be `O(N)`, you will use extra space though

Got to this solution after discussing with a co-worker

Comment: `zeros_found++` does not work in python. The correct syntax is `zeros_found += 1`

Comment: Should be +=1. Still, it fails on [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1] removing zeros

Comment: Thanks for pointing my increment fault out @Farhan.K, updated answer

Comment: @agorin yeah, zeros weren't being removed. Updated answer, just needed to assign new list to original

Comment: Works fine now. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can run-length encode the original data and make changes based on that representation:

```
In [12]: import itertools

In [13]: data = [1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0]

In [14]: N = 3

In [15]: def run_length_encode(it):
    ...:     for k, g in itertools.groupby(it):
    ...:         yield k, sum(1 for _ in g)
    ...:         

In [16]: s = itertools.chain.from_iterable([1 if n < N else k]*n for k, n in run_length_encode(data))

In [17]: list(s)
Out[17]: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```